# Send data to another program in C with pipes

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am not used to work with C in Linux so maybe I am asking something very simple here. But I am a bit stuck.

I have a program from another company which runs on a Linux terminal showing some messages, receiving some commands from the terminal (keyboard) and showing some answers when you send a command.

I have created a C program that runs 2 threads. One for receiving from the pipe and one for sending a command when a timeout is reached.

I think this is a very typical approach as this code can be found on the internet several times:

```
 if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
    perror("Error creating the pipe\n");
    return 1;
} else {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        close(pipefd[0]);                                                               // Close reading descriptor
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);                                                 // Redirect output flow to the pipe
        execl("../FolderApp", "App", "-n", "0", "-p", "/dev/ttyACM0", NULL);   // Execute the subprocess
        perror("Error executing the command\n");                                       // If we reach this line, there was a mistake executing the command
        exit(1);
    } else {
        pthread_create(&reading_th, NULL, promtReceiver, NULL);
        pthread_create(&sending_th, NULL, promtSender, NULL);
    }
}
```

Receiver works like a charm. I just use:

```
bytes_read = read(pipefd[0],
        &internal_packet.buffer[internal_packet.buf_length],
        sizeof(internal_packet.buffer) - internal_packet.buf_length - 1);
```

And I get everything from the other program.

But, whenever I try to send a command, I just get my command as if it were sent by the other application. I use:

```
 write(pipefd[1], "command\r\n", strlen("command\r\n"));
```

At first I thought that I was receiving an echo from the other application but no other response. Because the other application shows the echo of the input command (if it is ok) and then, the response. But, in case I sent a wrong command, I keep getting an echo. So, this is not comming from the other application.

Is it possible to do what I want to achieve? Should I try another approach?

Comment: I don't think you should be calling `fork()` twice.

Comment: Everything written to `pipefd[1]` will be read from `pipefd[0]`. Why are you surprised that you're getting that in the receiver? Pipes aren't two-way channels. If you need that, you need to use two pipes or `socketpair()`.

Comment: @Barmar Only one time. My fault while copying the code. Ok, that is what I suspected. I will try with 2 pipes and read about sockerpair()

Comment: It's way more helpful to us if you supply a [mre] i.e. program instead of snippets we have to assemble just to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between two instances of a program, using pipes in this way will not work because each instance of the program will have its own separate memory space. Unix pipes won't work as they are designed for interprocess communication within the same program that has been forked. So two instances of the same program using pipes will not work.

However, you can use named pipes (also known as FIFOs), which are a type of file that can be used for communication between unrelated processes.

Here is an example of how you can use named pipes:

The writer program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    // create the FIFO (named pipe)
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    char arr1[80];
    while (1)
    {
        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        fgets(arr1, 80, stdin);
        write(fd, arr1, strlen(arr1)+1);
        close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reader program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd1;

    // FIFO file path
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    // creating the named pipe (FIFO)
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    char str1[80];
    while (1)
    {
        // first open in read only and read
        fd1 = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY);
        read(fd1, str1, 80);

        // print the read string and close
        printf("User1: %s\n", str1);
        close(fd1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```